# how to encode url to json from barcode

Tags: java, android, json

I want to scan barcode that contains REST API, result.getContents will receive url .  I have try to fill barcode with json format without using uriparse below and it's work. My problem is how to convert rest api to json.

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (result != null){
            if (result.getContents() == null){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Result not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
             // if qrcode are fil
                try{
                    String url = Uri.parse(result.getContents())
                            .buildUpon()
                            .build()
                            .toString();
                    // converting the data json
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(url);
                    // setting value to textview
                    textViewName.setText(object.getString("ceramics_name"));
                    textViewDisplay.setText(object.getString("ceramics_category"));
                    textViewStorage.setText(object.getString("storage_stock"));
                    Toast.makeText(this, result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(this, result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }



            }
        }else{
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use gson library https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: @AnasMehar i found another way with volley, thanks for your advice